# Kernel of a minimalpolynom of a Endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm absolutely stuck with te following proof:

Let $V$ be a $K$-Vectorspace of Dimension $n$. Let the minomial polynomial of $A \in End(V)$
be $M_{A}(x) = x^{k}$

Show that $Ker(A^j) \supset Ker(A^{j-1})$  $\forall j \geq 1$
and that $Ker(A^{j-1}) \neq Ker(A^j) $ $\forall j \leq k$

There is even a follow up questions which I would try to solve on my own, if someone could post a sufficient solution to the above problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in\ker A^{j-1}$ then

$$A^j x=A(A^{j-1}x)=0$$
so $x\in\ker A^j$ and the inclusion follows.

Assume that  there's $j\le k$ such that $\ker A^{j-1}=\ker A^j$. Let $x\in\ker A^{j+1}$ then $A^{j}(Ax)=0$ so $Ax\in\ker A^j=\ker A^{j-1}$ hence $A^{j-1}(Ax)=A^jx=0$ so $x\in\ker A^j$ hence we proved that
$$\ker A^j=\ker A^{j+1}=\cdots=\ker A^k=V$$
hence $A^{j-1}=0$ which contradicts the minimality of $A^k=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$A^j x = A(A^{j-1}x)$ implies $\ker A^j \supseteq \ker A^{j-1}$.

$\ker A^j = \ker A^{j-1}$ for some $j\le k$ implies $\ker A^m = \ker A^{j-1}$ for  all $m \ge j$. In particular, $\ker A^k = \ker A^{j-1}$, which implies that $x^{j-1}$ annihilates $A$. This contradicts the hypothesis that $x^k$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$ since $j-1<k$.

Answer (score 1):

$Ker(A^j) \supset Ker(A^{j-1})$ comes from the definition of $Ker$.
If $x\in Ker(A^{j-1})$ then $A^{j-1}x=0$ then $A^jx=0$ then $x\in Ker(A^j)$

If $\exists j\leq k$: $Ker(A^{j-1})=Ker(A^j)$ you can prove$^*$ that $Ker(A^j)=Ker(A^{j+1})$ which leads to $Ker(A^{k-1})=Ker(A^k)=Ker(0)=V$ which means $x^k$ is not the minimal polynomial of $A$.

$^*$: you the fact that $Ker(A^j)=Im(A)\bigcap Ker(A^{j-1})$

Hope this help